# Is possible NSSortDescriptor sort NSObject with specific language first?

Tags: objective-c, nssortdescriptor

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                 initWithKey:@"surname"
                                 ascending:YES
                                 selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
```

I used this to sort my array but i want to show hebrew word first and then english is it possible.

Comment: You'll have to write your own comparator which takes into account the string's language.

Comment: You would have to use a custom `NSComparisonResult`. You can have a look there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32987086/sorting-array-having-special-characters-numbers-english-and-arabic-string-in-o